# AspCore T4 Generation Adding Reference To System.Runtime.DLL

Tags: c#, t4

I'm writing a project that generates code.  I need to load System.Runtime.Dll into the T4 Generator as it does not seem to be apart of System.Core.Dll anymore

In previous version of the code this template header would of sufficed

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
```

However, everything seems to be apart of the Nuget Packages now.  I would like a way to reference the System.Runtime.Dll v 4.1.0.0 universally so that it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After referencing the package via nuget you can do one of the following, if you are using asp.net core you can reference the package in your user folder (where all packages for all solutions are kept):

example:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages\Humanizer.Core\2.1.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Humanizer.dll" #>
```

or for pre .net core, reference the package form your solution folder:

example:

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\packages\Humanizer.1.37.7\lib\portable-win+net40+sl50+wp8+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Humanizer.dll" #>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out when I get home, I'm trying to make a shippable ASP.Net core code generator for Crud API's.  I'm just wondering if that definition will work with all computers

Comment: T4 templates only work with Visual Studio, which is usually windows, so this  should work. I don't think T4 templating is available in the Code IDE. Your project sounds interesting, we do something similar for our own projects.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know the tool didn't work on other platforms, I guess for now generation can only happen on windows,  The ASP.Net Core is frusterating with the runtime, because it keeps getting Runtime mismatches, but I really need this tool becuase when you're making enterprise architecture a lot of it is just fluff, so I figured I'd save myself hours and have it generate all the basic classes for me and I can override anything more complicated

Comment: Yep, I have some other posts about more cross platform code generation, but haven't found a better solution. pure cross platform and no dependency on the full framework is pretty hard right now anyway. 
We build CRUD for EF7, looking at the Entity classes, saves heaps of time.

Comment: Yeah I was just debating on writing a the code generation as a core dll and just say screw t4. It's so outdated and doesn't have intellisense. Im barely even using the tt. I'm using the entities to generate, dtos, contracts, adapters and services. That way I have syntax highlighting and direct referencing back to the original entity. So I don't have to look though a messy tt file

Comment: We use the plugin from Tangible which helps with intellisense etc but unfortunately there is no replacement for T4 or anything else that can do the same job.

Comment: Yeah, but none of the plugins work with vs 2017, have you heard of [scripty](https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Scripty-a-C-T4-Alternative)?